# How can I filter a vector of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, filter

I have a big vector of 10000 strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { v.push_back(generateRandomString(10)); }
```

I'd like to display the strings which contain "AB" as a substring. I tried:

```
std::vector<std::string> res;
res = std::copy_if(v, [](auto s) { return s.find("AB") != std::string::npos; });

cout << res;
```

But I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'copy_if(std::vectorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char >&, main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:1)>)'
> std::vectorstd::string b = std::copy_if(a, [](auto s) { return s.find("AB") != std::string::npos; });

**How can I filter a vector of strings and display only those which have "AB" as a substring?**

(Will this be efficient if `v` contains 50MB of data?)

Comment: It may be worth reading [the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines (untested):

```
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
    [](const std::string& s) { return s.find("AB") != std::string::npos; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get `error: 'ostream_iterator' is not a member of 'std'`.

Comment: you'll probably want to use `std::back_inserter` instead of `std::ostream_iterator` if you want to copy to another vector

Comment: Have you included the header that [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) suggests should be included before using `std::ostream_iterator`?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Quoth the OP: "I'd like to **display** those..." Emphasis mine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, for further use, indeed I'd like to copy it to `res` and then display `res`.

Comment: Then yes, replace the third argument with `std::back_inserter(res)`. To then display `res`, you could use `std::copy` with `std::ostream_iterator` - we leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Seems to be: `std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(res), [](auto s) { return s.find("AB") != std::string::npos; });`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an efficient solution for just printing the strings you are interested in, you should avoid creating an intermediate data structure, i.e. you shouldn't use `std::copy_if`. Since [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) you can use the range adaptor `std::views::filter` from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) together with a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), as follows:

```
auto ab = [](const auto& s) { return s.find("AB") != std::string::npos; };
for (auto const& s : v | std::views::filter(ab))
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

This solution does not create a temporary vector for the filtered strings, because the view adaptor creates a range that doesn't contain elements. The resulting range is just a view over the vector `v`, but with a customized iteration behavior.

As of [C++23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B23) you can use [std::string::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/contains) to make the code even shorter and more readable, as follows:

```
auto ab = [](const auto& s) { return s.contains("AB"); };
for (auto const& s : v | std::views::filter(ab))
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Spw6yygLMIGCa0e7)

However, if you want to also store the filtered result for further use, then you can combine the above solution with [`std::ranges::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy) from the [algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> res;
std::ranges::copy(v | std::views::filter(ab), std::back_inserter(res));
for (auto const& s : res)
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OSbCBETwlVDReQUo)